# Conflicting written versus parenthetical days in a commercial contract

Tags: united-states, contract-law, pennsylvania

In a commercial contract, if the written and parenthetical days in a clause are in disagreement, which takes precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Uniform Commercial Code § 3-114](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-114) ([adopted by all 50 states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Commercial_Code)) says:

> If an instrument contains contradictory terms, typewritten terms prevail over printed terms, handwritten terms prevail over both, and **words prevail over numbers**.

This text is incorporated without modification in Pennsylvania in [Title 13, § 3114](http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/consCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&ttl=13&div=3&chpt=31&sctn=14&subsctn=0).

([Bryan Garner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_A._Garner)—I'll let his Wikipedia page speak for itself—says you should [avoid word-numeral doublets](http://press-pubs.uchicago.edu/garner/documents/section39.html) so that this isn't even an issue.)